# Android Spinner in Toolbar Arrow

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-spinner

I want to have a Spinner in my Toolbar.
However, the Spinner doesn't have any dropdown arrow, as the default Android Spinner does.

How do I make it have an arrow?

This is my code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleMarginTop="15dp">
      <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/Location_Spinner"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
```

Fragment where I show the spinner:

```
 var spinner = Activity.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.Location_Spinner);
 var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(Activity, Resource.Array.locations_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
 adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
 spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

Any ideas why there isn't an arrow?

Comment: I don't see it in your code, but are you setting a background for spinner by any chance?

Comment: @Iulian No, I'm not setting a background.

Comment: @lulian Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what's happening. Maybe one solution would be to create a similar background and set it for spinner or try to check on multiple devices (maybe it's a bug only on some phones)

Comment: @IulianPopescu tried setting the background, but the arrow fills up the entire spinner instead of just being on the side.

Comment: And you tried your code on emulator or real device?

Comment: @lulian on an emulator

Comment: Try on a real device, maybe the emulator has a problem

Comment: @lulian Doesn't work on real device either. Perhaps it is some issue of styling? However there's a big mess with all the styling of spinners in Android.

Comment: I don't know the problem. I just checked the xamarin doc and it's the same as your code. I will try something a little bit later and if I have any success I'll let you know

Comment: @lulian Ok. Thanks.